# Vue Test Utils: Props of slots undefined

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vue-test-utils

Currently, i am using Vue.js to develop a front-end app and i am using Vue Test Utils + Jest to test my components.

I have a component which wraps a list of components which essentially are slots.

In beforeEach function i mock this slots.

```
    stepContent1 = {
    render(h) {
      return h(StepContent, { props: { title: "Step1", subTitle: 'Subtitle for Step 1', stepKey: 'stepOne' } });
    },
  };

  stepContent2 = {
    render(h) {
      return h(StepContent, { props: { title: "Step2", subTitle: 'Subtitle for Step 2', stepKey: 'stepTwo' } });
    },
  };

  stepContent3 = {
    render(h) {
      return h(StepContent, { props: { title: "Step3", subTitle: 'Subtitle for Step 3', stepKey: 'stepThree' } });
    },
  };
```

Then i pass the slots in shallowMount

```
const wrapper = shallowMount(FormWizard, {
slots: {
  default: [stepContent1, stepContent2, stepContent3],
},
mocks,
```

});

If i check the prop with this method.

```
wrapper.findAll(StepContent).wrappers[0].vm.stepKey
```

I can get the slot children prop. But, if you want to do a black-box testing, like triggering a click within FormWizard which depends on StepContent props then the prop of the StepContent slots are undefined.

Any idea why this might happen?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did u solved this?